# Getting and error when i put my updateScore function corona

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

im getting an error here is the link http://cdn.imghack.se/images/b902d2e1eea1f477e1a649f6004f34f3.png , i am using the director class im having the error when i put this in my code

```
        local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
        local file = io.open( path, "w+" )
        local reader, er = io.open( path, "r" )
        local contents = reader:read("*n")

                local function update( event )
                updateBackgrounds()
                updateSpeed()
                updateMonster()
                updateBlocks()
                updateBlasts()
                updateSpikes()
                updateGhosts()
                checkCollisions()
                updateScore()
                end


            function updateScore()

                        if (stopscore == false) then
                                score = score + 1
                                scoreText.text = "score: " .. score
                                scoreText:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
                                scoreText.x = 0
                                scoreText.y = 30
                                print (er)
                        else
                                if(  contents == nil ) then 
                                        file:write(score)   
                                        file:close()
                                        reader:close()  

                                else
                                        file:close()
                                        reader:close()
                                end

                                 if ( contents < score and monster.isAlive == false)
                                        file:write(score)   
                                        file:close()
                                        reader:close()
                                else
                                        file:close()
                                        reader:close()
                                end


                        end     
             end
```

can someone help me? still posting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntax error, check this :

```
   function updateScore()

                if (stopscore == false) then
                        score = score + 1
                        scoreText.text = "score: " .. score
                        scoreText:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
                        scoreText.x = 0
                        scoreText.y = 30
                else
                        if( contents < score and monster.isAlive == false) then  
                                file:write(score)   
                                file:close()
                                reader:close()                            
                        else
                                file:close()
                                reader:close()
                        end
                end     
     end
```

Comment: One more syntax error "monster.isAlive = false".. Edited my answer

Comment: thanks now its working but another problem arises attempt to compare string to a number can you check if i used my locals the right way? sorry cause im fairly new in lua and corona

Comment: I believe you shoud use tonumber(contents) < score

Comment: i changed my code a bit and again there is an error ill reuplaod it

Comment: its now back to the same error dont know what did i do wrong :( i replaced the local contents = reader:read("*a") to local contents = reader:read("*n") cause it reads only the number but when i print the er its saying that its nil even though i put a number in the txt file before i run it after running it terminal saying its nil

Comment: yes i did try that, even if i put a value on the text file if i run it and print it the value returns nil even though i put a value on it